# How to Rename the filename before uploading to s3 bucket ?angular file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, angular8

I have set file to be uploaded in s3 bucket,I need to add timestamp before file extension. I m working this code in angular 8 .
this is the method I'm using.

```
onFileChange(files: FileList) {

for (let fItr in files) {
if (fItr != 'length' && fItr != 'item') {
// var fileExtension = '.' + files[fItr].name.split('.').pop();
// files[fItr].name= Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) + new Date().getTime() + fileExtension;
this.attachment.push(files[fItr]);
this.fileToUpload.push(files.item(parseInt(fItr)));
```

}

sample input

```
crawlling.php
fileupload.csv
fileupload.pptx
loading.mp4
```

sample output (i need the files to be uploaded like this)

```
crawlling_20180215022222.php
fileupload_20190419062612.csv
fileupload_20200419082612.pptx
loading_20180910081329.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to append to blob and create new file and push this

```
onFileChange(files: FileList) {       
      for (let fItr in files) {
          if (fItr != 'length' && fItr != 'item') {
              var fileExtension = '.' + files[fItr].name.split('.')[1];
              var prefix=files[fItr].name.split('.')[0];
              var name= prefix+this.convertDate()+ Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) + new Date().getTime() + fileExtension;
              var blob = fItr.slice(0, fItr.size, fItr.type); 
              var newFile = new File([blob], name, {type: fItr.type});
          }
       }
 }
convertDate(){
    var date=new Date();
    day=date.getDate();
    month=date.getMonth();
    month=month+1;
    if((String(day)).length==1)
    day='0'+day;
    if((String(month)).length==1)
    month='0'+month;
    return date.getFullYear()+""+month+""+ day;
}
```

Comment: Hi @pc_coder ,conversion is happening  but the prefix file name which i gave while uploading has changed to someother random name .( dora.png is the file name which i upload and it has converted into ts3wv21594228931179.png  )

Comment: I just opened your comment line. I will  update now with your expected result.